# MobileSubstrate: MSHookFunction example

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I am trying to write a MobileSubstrate plugin which hooks into a C-method. I tried to edit the famous "ExampleHook", by just writing a demo MSHook and hook it in the Initialize method.
This is probably too optimistic and it doesn't work. But I cannot find anywhere a simple example of a MSHookFunction(). There is barely information about this on the Internet. It might be possible I misunderstood the whole concept of MSHookFunction.

Please, can anybody help me out with a little example code? I would deeply appreciate any help.

Best regards,
Marc Backes

Comment: Nevermind. I think I have it.

Comment: Can you help me with compiling such a class? I am trying to use the following class in my project http://pastie.org/1882125 when I compile it ,it says MSHookfunction not found.Please help me :(

Answer (score 11):

I realize you have found this, but I am posting this answer to help whoever else may be needing this.

A simple example can be found at [the MobileSubstrate article](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate#Example_code) on the iPhone Dev Wiki, and an actual example of this in a project is [at this bit](https://github.com/conradev/UserAgentFaker/blob/master/CFNetworkHooks.xm) of *User Agent Faker*.

But what is an answer without an actual explanation? Therefore, here we go!

`void MSHookFunction(void* function, void* replacement, void** p_original);` is the function definition for `MSHookFunction`, the magic function which causes your function `X()` to be interposed by `Y()`, for instance.

That is, when a program commonly would call `X()`, the call will be redirected to `Y()` instead. This is pretty much a basic explanation of *function interposing*.

Now, what are the parameters, and their usefulness?

- `function` is a function pointer to the function you want to interpose. That would be a function pointer to `X()`, in our quick explanation.
- `replacement` is a function pointer to the function you want `function` to be interposed with. In our quick explanation, that would be a function pointer to `Y()`.
- `p_original` is a pointer to a function pointer, which from now on will point to what `function` used to be.

  The reason this is there is simple: If you intend to modify behavior, but not suppress it, you'll still need to call what `X()` used to be. But a common call to `X()` wouldn't work as intended, as it would end calling `Y()` instead of the default `function`.

  Therefore, you have a function pointer to call `X()` as if it wasn't interposed.

Now, explaining the devwiki example:

```
static void (*original_CFShow)(CFTypeRef obj);  // a function pointer to store the original CFShow().
void replaced_CFShow(CFTypeRef obj) {           // our replacement of CFShow().
  printf("Calling original CFShow(%p)...", obj);
  original_CFShow(obj);                         // calls the original CFShow.
  printf(" done.\n");
}
...
// hook CFShow to our own implementation.
MSHookFunction(CFShow, replaced_CFShow, &original_CFShow);
// From now on any call to CFShow will pass through replaced_CFShow first.
...
CFShow(CFSTR("test"));
```

Here, we:

1. Pass a pointer to `CFShow`, the function we want to change default behavior from as the `function` parameter.
2. Pass a pointer to the function we just created, `replaced_CFShow` as the `replacement` parameter. That is, whenever `CFShow` would be called by default, `replaced_CFShow` will be called instead.
3. We pass a pointer to the `original_CFShow` function pointer as the `p_original` parameter. Since we still want the things `CFShow` still does by itself to be done inside our replacement function, we call it.