# (iOS, TheOS) %hook into global app function

Tags: objective-c, ios7, hook, jailbreak, theos

I am looking for a global `function` for apps in iOS 7.

More specifically, I want to injected code into the app(s) upon launch, which will only effect the `app`, and not the `SpringBoard`.

I have tried a couple of things but they only affect the `SpringBoard`:

```
%hook SBApplicationIcon
    - (id)application {
        return %orig;
    }
    - (id)initWithApplication:(id)arg1 {
        return %orig;
    }
%end

%hook SBApplicationController
    - (id)init {
         return %orig;
    }
%end

%hook SBUIController
    - (void)launchIcon:(id)arg1 fromLocation:(int)arg2 {
        %orig;
    }
    - (id)contentView {
        return %orig;
    }
%end

%hook SBApplication
    - (void)didLaunch:(id)arg1 {
        %orig;
    }
%end
```

These are just a couple of examples of `functions` I've tried.

I suspect the filter needs to be changed as well, but that depends on where the function is located ofc (`com.apple.springboard` is set atm).

I was received a tip to set the filter to `*`, but that doesn't do me much good if I don't know what `function` to `%hook`.

Please explain your answer if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround using **NSDistributedNotificationCenter** which will do what you want.

First of all, you need to set your filter to **com.apple.UIKit** so your dynamic library get's hooked into all processes.

Then create a Class (.h and .m file) and lets name it *GlobalFunction*:

**GlobalFunction.h file**

```
@interface GlobalFunction: NSObject
@end
```

**GlobalFunction.m file**

```
#import "GlobalFunction.h"

@implementation GlobalFunction
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(globalNotificationReceived:) name:@"info.ilendemli.globalNotification" object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)globalNotificationReceived:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Notification Received");
}
@end
```

and in your **Tweak.xm** do the following:

```
#import "GlobalFunction.h"

%hook SpringBoard
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(id)application {
    %orig;
    [GlobalFunction new];
}
%end
```

so the Class gets initialized when **SpringBoard** loads up. Then use:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"info.ilendemli.globalNotification" object:nil];
```

to post a notification so the method gets called.

I haven't tested this but it should work, and it's similar to something i made before, which works great.

## Edit #1:

To execute the method on app-launch add the following in your **Tweak.xm** file:

```
static NSArray *blackList = @[ @"MailAppController", @"SpringBoard", @"FBWildeApplication" ];

%hook UIApplication

- (void)_run {
    NSString *classString = NSStringFromClass([self class]);

    if (![blackList containsObject:classString]) {
        [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"info.ilendemli.globalNotification" object:nil];
    }

    %orig;
}

%end
```

## Edit #2:

Edited the post to remove %ctor, because that probably wouldn't work. Added alternative approach by hooking SpringBoard and initializing the Class there.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is only running in **SpringBoard** because you've chosen to *hook* methods in SpringBoard classes (e.g. `SBUIController`, `SBApplicationController`, etc.), and your filter is set to only hook SpringBoard itself.

[Try checking out the MobileSubstrate docs here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate)

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you simply want any method that will run in all normal "apps"?

If so, you might change your filter to hook everything that uses UIKit:

```
Filter = {
  Bundles = (com.apple.UIKit);
};
```

You could then try using `MSHookFunction()` to hook a C-function, [as shown in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11820393/119114).

In your code, try hooking [UIApplicationMain()](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain), which I believe all normal apps would use.

### Update:

Another potential technique would be to hook any of the usual launch callback methods from the `UIApplicationDelegate` *protocol*.  In order to using hooking, though, you need to discover which **classes** implement this protocol.  [See this answer for an example of doing this (with another protocol)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20735457/119114).